# PHP Post - Executar function antes do Submit

Tags: php, post

Não estou conseguindo fazer o seguinte:

Digamos que a url do meu sistema é www.meusistema.com.br e preciso enviar informações do meu sistema para outro...

No meu sistema tenho o seguinte form **www.meusistema.com.br/index.php**:

```
<form method="POST" name="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="texto_exemplo_form" id="texto_exemplo_form">   
    <input type="hidden" name="exemplo_hidden" value="<?php echo $exemplo; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

<?php
    $exemplo = "";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $exemplo = "Texto do Form vai ser concatenado com este...";

        $txt = $_POST['texto_exemplo_form'];   
        $exemplo = $exemplo . $txt;
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'document.getElementById("exemplo_hidden").value = ' . $txt . ';';
        echo 'document.getElementById("form").action="www.outrosistema.com/gerarpdf.php";';
        echo 'document.getElementById("form").submit()';
        echo '</script>';
    }
?>
```

Para o sistema **www.outrosistema.com/gerarpdf.php** preciso enviar os dados digitados no campo **texto_exemplo**  concatenado com o texto da variável **exemplo**

Resumindo:

Preciso executar uma função `PHP` para tratar os dados do form antes do `submit` para **www.outrosistema.com/gerarpdf.php**.

Editado... Obs: `echo 'document.getElementById("form").submit()';`  <--- **Não faz o submit.**

**RESOLVIDO**

Não estou fazendo mais o `submit` direto para o **outrosistema**, criei um php "intermediário" que trata o submit e envia os dados para o **outrosistema**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function() {
               .
               .
               .
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Pode detalhar um pouco mais o seu problema? Você quer que uma requisição `HTTP` POST seja feita do seu site para outro site?

Comment: Isso o submit (post) do meu site para o outro. Isto tranquilo... Mas o que não to sabendo é tratar os dados do campo "exemplo" (hidden) antes do submit

Comment: Veja este link do [stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)